# TabBarController is keeping his sub controllers after calling popToRootViewController()

Tags: ios, swift

My root view is an TabBarController with 3 Tabs:

```
    -> TabBarController  -> Tab1 (Login)  -> ViewController
                         -> Tab2          -> NavigationController1 -> ViewController1 (with TextField1) -> ViewController2
                         -> Tab3          -> NavigationController2 -> ViewController3 (with TextField2) -> ViewController4
```

When logout, I want:
  1. Destroying all sub controllers with data in Textfield1 and Textfield2 in Tab2 and Tab3
  2. Selecting Tab1

I tried to calling the popToRootViewController() of all navigation controllers of TabBarController and after that, I Call self.selectedIndex = 0 in the TabBarController.

```
    fileprivate func popAllNavigationControllersToRoot() {
        if let viewControllers = self.viewControllers {
            for viewController in viewControllers {
                if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
                    navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func onDidChangeLoginState(_ notification:Notification) {
        popAllNavigationControllersToRoot()
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    }
```

This works fine, but when I relogin after

```
onDidChangeLoginState(..)
```

and switch to Tab2 or Tab3, the TextField1/TextField2 contains the old values before calling onDidChangeLoginState(..). It seems that the ViewControllers are not destroying when calling popToRootViewController. Do I something wrong?

I now the best practice would be

```
  LoginScreen -> TabBarController -> Tab1 ...
                                  -> Tab2 ...
```

But the login view inside the Tab1 is set by PO.

Answer (score 0):

Since the TabBar Controller keeps a hold of the view controller objects the textfield values are not going to be removed by itself. When `logout()` is called you can remove the textfield values from both the tabs and reset the data. Another option is that when user logs in then the textfield values in Both tabs will be set to empty strings.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I thought that I have to spend the time to notify every view controller about the logout. Okay, I guess there's no other way when the TabBarController keeps the view controllers :( Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- Unless you tell it to do otherwise, the tab bar controller is going to retain its view controllers (`ViewController`, `NavigationController1`, and `NavigationController2`.)
- Unless you tell them to do otherwise, both navigation controllers are going to retain their root view controllers (`ViewController1` and `ViewController3`, respectively).

Instead of popping to root, if you want new instances of these, you can reset the whole stack. For example:

```
let nav1 = tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as! UINavigationController
let newInstanceOfVC1 = ViewController1() // or initialize from storyboard

nav1.setViewControllers([newInstanceOfVC1], animated: true)
```

Comment: Yes u're right, that should be working. I'm going to test it tomorrow :)

Comment: Perfect! it works to reset the stack with nav1. setViewControllers(..). Thank you very much!